# Typechecking with conditional parameters

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to use typing with a function that has conditional parameters, that works like this:

```
from typing import Optional, Union


class Foo:
    some_param_to_check: str = 'foo_name'
    one_param_exclusive_to_foo: int


class Bar:
    some_param_to_check: str = 'bar_name'
    another_param_exclusive_to_bar: str


def some_process_that_returns_a_bool(
    f_or_b: Union[Foo, Bar],
    a_name: str,
) -> bool:
    return f_or_b.some_param_to_check == a_name


def do_something_with_foo_or_bar(
    foo: Optional[Foo],
    bar: Optional[Bar],
    some_name: str,
) -> bool:
    if not foo and not bar:
        raise ValueError('You need to specify either "foo" or "bar".')

    # I added this explicit type hint after the first error, hoping it would solve the issue:
    foo_or_bar: Union[Foo, Bar]  # later becomes Union[Foo, Bar, None]
    foo_or_bar = foo if foo else bar

    return some_process_that_returns_a_bool(foo_or_bar, some_name)


foo_obj = Foo()
bar_obj = Bar()

# This will work:
do_something_with_foo_or_bar(foo_obj, bar_obj, 'test_string')

# This will also work:
do_something_with_foo_or_bar(foo_obj, None, 'test_string')

# This too:
do_something_with_foo_or_bar(None, bar_obj, 'test_string')

# But this should not:
do_something_with_foo_or_bar(None, None, 'test_string')
```

To add more context:

The function works by expecting `foo`, or, if not available, `bar`. If `foo` is not `None`, `bar` will essentially be ignored.

When checking with mypy, it complains about:

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[Foo, Bar, None]", variable has type "Union[Foo, Bar]"
```

(I'm guessing because of the `Optional` in the parameter type hints.)

If I then add `None` as the type hint for `foo_or_bar` then the error becomes:

```
error: Item "None" of "Union[Foo, Bar, None]" has no attribute "some_param_to_check"
```

How would I fix this so that mypy stops complaining (while still keeping the type hints)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is just a mypy issue. Its type inference system is not clever enough to recognize that your `if not foo and not bar` block that raises an exception excludes the double `None` case later on (since it can't conclusively infer anything about either type in isolation). There doesn't seem to be a good way to directly fix the type hinting, but you could instead change the logic a bit to separate the cases more clearly, and mypy should understand it better:

```
def do_something_with_foo_or_bar(
    foo: Optional[Foo],
    bar: Optional[Bar],
    some_name: str,
) -> bool:
    foo_or_bar: Union[Foo, Bar]
    if foo:
        foo_or_bar = foo
    elif bar:
        foo_or_bar = bar
    else:
        raise ValueError('You need to specify either "foo" or "bar".')

    return some_process_that_returns_a_bool(foo_or_bar, some_name)
```

You could also get rid of the `foo_or_bar` variable all together and just put two different function calls in the `if` and `elif` blocks, using `foo` or `bar` as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because in `some_process_that_returns_a_bool` you are trying to access `some_param_to_check` on a value that can be `None` and `None` does not have that property.

If `some_process_that_returns_a_bool` should accept `None` as a possible value for `f_or_b` , then you should check for `None` before trying to access any properties.

```py
def some_process_that_returns_a_bool(
    f_or_b: Union[Foo, Bar, None],
    a_name: str,
) -> bool:
    if f_or_b is None:
      # Handle None...
      return False
    else:
      return f_or_b.some_param_to_check == a_name
```

This way you will only try to access `some_param_to_check` when `f_or_b` is not `None` and else you will return `False` when `f_or_b` is `None`.

But please handle None in whatever way makes sense for your application.

Comment: `Union[Optional[Foo], Optional[Bar]` is a confusing way of writing `Union[Foo, Bar, None]`

Comment: Anyway, this is one way to handle it, although, the OP doesn't indicate what should happen if the argument is `None`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're right. The intended point with the example was only that a None check should be implemented if None is an intended possible value for the argument. I will edit the text to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my $0.02 to @Blckknght answer:

This solves the problem with inner type checking (no errors inside function body, if you fix a missing annotation), but [doesn't help](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=5785ee08c8ef423e3db6043326d11b2f) external callers.

To achieve typing "one or another, but never none of them", you can use overloads:

```py
from typing import Optional, Union, overload


class Foo:
    some_param_to_check: str = 'foo_name'
    one_param_exclusive_to_foo: int


class Bar:
    some_param_to_check: str = 'bar_name'
    another_param_exclusive_to_bar: str


def some_process_that_returns_a_bool(
    f_or_b: Union[Foo, Bar],
    a_name: str,
) -> bool:
    return f_or_b.some_param_to_check == a_name

@overload
def do_something_with_foo_or_bar(
    foo: Foo,
    bar: Optional[Bar],
    some_name: str,
) -> bool: ...
@overload
def do_something_with_foo_or_bar(
    foo: Optional[Foo],
    bar: Bar,
    some_name: str,
) -> bool: ...
def do_something_with_foo_or_bar(
    foo: Optional[Foo],
    bar: Optional[Bar],
    some_name: str,
) -> bool:
    foo_or_bar: Union[Foo, Bar]  # This annotation was missing
    if foo:
        foo_or_bar = foo
    elif bar:
        foo_or_bar = bar
    else:
        raise ValueError('You need to specify either "foo" or "bar".')

    return some_process_that_returns_a_bool(foo_or_bar, some_name)
    

do_something_with_foo_or_bar(Foo(), Bar(), '')
do_something_with_foo_or_bar(None, Bar(), '')
do_something_with_foo_or_bar(Foo(), None, '')
do_something_with_foo_or_bar(None, None, '')  # Line 51
```

And voila:

```
main.py:51: error: No overload variant of "do_something_with_foo_or_bar" matches argument types "None", "None", "str"  [call-overload]
main.py:51: note: Possible overload variants:
main.py:51: note:     def do_something_with_foo_or_bar(foo: Foo, bar: Optional[Bar], some_name: str) -> bool
main.py:51: note:     def do_something_with_foo_or_bar(foo: Optional[Foo], bar: Bar, some_name: str) -> bool
```

Here's [a playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=dfcd116a118377101e57b3eb2d6f139e).